# Stored Procedure works but not when called with ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following function to update some data in the database:

```
public Boolean ModificarDireccion(DireccionBE dirBE) {
    con.ConnectionString = conection.GetCon();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "PERSONA.ActualizarDireccion";

    try {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_direccion", dirBE.Id_direccion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_direccion", dirBE.Tipo_direccion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_persona", dirBE.Id_persona);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir_pais", dirBE.Dir_pais);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir_provincia", dirBE.Dir_provincia);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir_ciudad", dirBE.Dir_ciudad);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir_distrito", dirBE.Dir_distrito);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir_linea_1", dirBE.Dir_linea_1);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir_linea_2", dirBE.Dir_linea_2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir_codigo_postal", dirBE.Dir_codigo_postal);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        success = true;
    } catch (SqlException x) {
        success = false;
        throw new Exception(x.Message);
    } finally {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
            con.Close();
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    }
    return success;
}
```

With the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PERSONA].[ActualizarDireccion]
    (
        @id_direccion [int],
        @tipo_direccion [tinyint],
        @id_persona [int],
        @dir_pais [tinyint],
        @dir_provincia [int],
        @dir_ciudad [int],
        @dir_distrito [int],
        @dir_linea_1 [nvarchar](100),
        @dir_linea_2 [nvarchar](100),
        @dir_codigo_postal [varchar](10)
    )
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE PERSONA.DIRECCION
        SET  tipo_direccion = @tipo_direccion, id_persona = @id_persona, dir_pais = @dir_pais, dir_provincia = @dir_provincia, dir_ciudad = @dir_ciudad, dir_distrito = @dir_distrito, dir_linea_1 = @dir_linea_1, dir_linea_2 = @dir_linea_2, dir_codigo_postal = @dir_codigo_postal
        WHERE (id_direccion = @id_direccion)
    COMMIT
```

This is the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [PERSONA].[TELEFONO](
    [id_telefono] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tipo_telefono] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [id_persona] [int] NOT NULL,
    [codigo_pais] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [campo_1] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [campo_2] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [campo_3] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [ext] [varchar](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__TELEFONO_bf60e690] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_telefono] ASC,
    [tipo_telefono] ASC,
    [id_persona] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

When I call this function its not updating the database. However if I manually use it in SSMS I can successfully update the data. What did I miss?

I tried debugging, going step by step and the object "dirBE" has the right data in it, however the change just does not get put into the database. There are no errors, nothing.

Comment: What exception you get? There should be some response from SQL Server. Can you please debug and check where it is getting stuck.

Comment: Check this answer. The transaction cause this problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21628353/3308881

Comment: @AniketBhansali I did but I did not see anything at all. Thats whats the strangest part. I stepped through it several times and the object gets updated in the code but not the database.

Comment: @moinmaroofi The transactions are handled in the database and I do not use them in the client applications. Only in the stored procedure. Do I still have to declare them in the client application?

Comment: I guess, try changing `COMMIT` to `COMMIT TRANSACTION`

Comment: Debug your code and watch cmd before line `code`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); `code` and check the parameters

Comment: also use try catch in your store SP and  use return value to debug it.

Comment: As an aside, best practice is **not** to use [AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @DaleK it's far less important/an issue with an SP.. (as the first comment on the article says). The original blog authors complaint with AddWithValue is that the parameter could end up being the wrong type when used in a query predicate, badly affecting performance. In a sproc the values are typed for the procedure so the problems you might run into would really only involve issues of value conversion ahead of the time the parameters are used in a query

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% certain that a) you're looking in the correct database and b) there is definitely a record in that db with that exact value contained in your `dir_Be.Id_direccion`? I wish I'd had a dollar for every time the answer to a "db not updating" question had turned out to be 1) a file based database being attached upon every run of the program, with the dev looking in the db in the project folder and the program updating the db in the bin folder or 2) a typo in some parameter used in a where clause.

Comment: @CaiusJard I'd still argue that its best practice in general even if the risk is less in this case. Its important to know one's parameters datatypes and code them correctly.

Comment: You posted the create table for a different one.

Comment: As an aside, your catch block is poor for various reasons: you don't need to set a return value if you're throwing, you shouldn't catch an exception and throw a new when you can just use the throw keyword alone to rethrow the original with all its stacktrace preserved, you shouldn't throw a general one at all. This catch block does nothing for you and should be removed to a try/finally or the entire try done away with in favour of a using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go. If it works, there is something wrong with your code, and visual studio will have generated a working code for you that you can copy (or just use)

- add a new item of type DataSet to your project
- open it - you see a blank gray surface
- Right click it and choose Add New.. Query
- configure your connection string into the dialog (new connection string)
- read this, proceeding from step 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/using-existing-stored-procedures-for-the-typed-dataset-s-tableadapters-cs

  - a quick recap of the steps is: "use existing stored procedure", series of wizard steps to utilize the existing stored procedure, picking which procedure, picking a method name, picking a return value strategy

Now you can right click on the query you made inside the table adapter and choose Preview, to use VS to test running it etc

To use it in your own code, do like:

```
new YourQueriesTableAdapterName().YourChosenMethodName(
  dirBE.id_direccion, 
  ...
);
```

The ide definitely generates working code (that you can find in the YourDataSet.Designer.cs if you want to copy it out, or you can leave it in there and just use the tableadapter - it's essentially the same thing as you're doing with your code, creating a separate class that calls a stored procedure) so if this suffers the same problem as yours then I'd say it comes down to one of a few things:

- you're looking in a different db to what your program is updating
- the value you're passing for id_direccion does not exist in the table
- there has been some value conversion error or mismatch of expectations that means the value you think c# is sending and the value it is actually sending, are different (see above mentioned error)

er.. and that's about it!

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conection.GetCon()))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PERSONA.ActualizarDireccion", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_direccion", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dirBE.Id_direccion;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipo_direccion", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = dirBE.Tipo_direccion;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_persona", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dirBE.Id_persona;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dir_pais", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = dirBE.Dir_pais;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dir_provincia", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dirBE.Dir_provincia;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dir_ciudad", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dirBE.Dir_ciudad;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dir_distrito", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dirBE.Dir_distrito;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dir_linea_1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dirBE.Dir_linea_1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dir_linea_2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dirBE.Dir_linea_2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dir_codigo_postal", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dirBE.Dir_codigo_postal;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work with this method. Thanks

Comment: @dominique120 Do you get an error or it just does not inset. Also please post the CreateTable code for your table and I'll see if I can duplicate.

Comment: I've added the table structure.